# Can we use space to achieve absolute zero for a quantum computer?

Tags: quantum-state

Why can't we use space to maintain absolute zero temperature required by the qubit chips and connect it to a satellite to perform computations?

Comment: Because outer space is not at absolute zero, it's around 2.7 Kelvin. We can make things a lot cooler in labs. I also don't think there is a meaningful sense in which we could hope to make the temperature of our system and the environment absolute zero but rather we can just look to get very close.

Comment: Welcome to QCSE! In addition to the issues already mentioned, shielding the quantum computer from cosmic rays would probably be much harder in outer space.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned by *Rammus* average temperature in space is 2.7 K while quantum processor are cooled to 15 mK (e.g. IBM Q). There are objects with lower temperature than 2.7 K in the space - black holes. But as you can see this option is *very unpractical*.

Moreover, I would add that it is not possible to reach absolute zero. This is forbidden by third law of thermodynamics. See details [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Third_law_of_thermodynamics#Absolute_zero).